# How to explain this construct in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am learning ts, and I have stumbled upon this piece of code

```
export const Field:<T> (x:T) => T;
```

I can't wrap my head around it.

It does look like the function definition below

```
type myFunction<T> = (x: T) => T
```

so I would see it as anonymous type definition but am I correct, how to use it?

Comment: Is this in a `.d.ts` file or `.ts` file?

Comment: it's in a .d.ts file.

Comment: It's declaring that this module exports something named `Field`, and the type of `Field` is `<T>(x: T) => T`, commonly called the identity function.

Comment: How would js that matches this Field definition look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<T>(x: T) => T
```

Is the type of an identity function. It uses a generic type parameter `T` set by the type of the argument `x`, and returns an object of type `T`. Or more simply, it returns the type that it received as an argument.

The javascript implementation would be simply:

```
(x) => x
```

To implement that type in Typescript, you might do:

```
const fn: Field = <T>(x: T) => x
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.6.4&preserveConstEnums=true&jsx=0&preserveValueImports=false&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false&inlineSources=false&preserveWatchOutput=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEygXigHgCoD4oAUAHgFzYCU6+2A3AFB0DGA9gHYDOwUAZqybAhToseYvwpUoRBiw5cAThGABXeawjIAagENEy6Bl4EAjACYAzOToB6a1HtQAegH4gA)